# doing a list of ids in a query using group clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get another colum, where it can get all the ids of the counts it have, like if the count column named as total has 2 - the ids should actually be those ids which matched the criteria of groupby

I tried with this code but it is failing

```
SELECT  message,type, count(1) as total, 
STUFF((
SELECT ',' + id 
FROM dbo.testing md
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM testing
GROUP BY message,type 
HAVING count(1) > 1;
```

Error i am getting:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT message, type, count(1) as total, 
       STUFF( (SELECT N',' + CONVERT(NVCHAR(MAX), id)
               FROM dbo.testing t2
               WHERE t2.message = t.message and t2.type = t.type
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
              ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''
            )
FROM testing t
GROUP BY message,type 
HAVING count(1) > 1;
```

This fixes the logic but it doesn't explain the syntax error you were getting.

Comment: Error gone with this fix, I just had to do this: `cast(id  as nvarchar(max)) as id` to make it work, but can i ask another question, i want to populate a field called `eid` starting from `1` to the number of records i have and each record have `1` or `5` or `10` `ids` which we just figured out lik: if the `ids` column have `5 ids` like `18,19,20,21,22` for all these the `eid` will be `1`